# Solving Linear Equation in compressive sensing

Tags: matrices, analysis

I have some known numbers xi of length 1024 within range $(0,255)$ and I know sums $y_i$ obtained by projecting xi on to matrix $A$ as $Ax=y$.

I know all $A_{ij} ∈ {0,1, -1}$. Moreover matrix dimension is $256 \times 1024$ in which each row has exactly $16 +1's$ and $16 -1's $entries and remaining entries equal to zero.

With known xi and yi, how could I find rows of matrix.

If entries in the matrix limited to only to $\{0,1\}$, then I could solve using subset sum problem. Is there any similar way to solve above mentioned problem?

How many solutions does each row have?